# How do we check version of Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, version

How do we check version of Oracle on which we are working?

How do we check the version of the interface on which we are working?

I have tried

```
select v$ from version ;
```

Comment: `select * from v$version;` should work.

Comment: A simple google search should have been enough.

Comment: Agree with Lalit, you could have used google for this. That would have been much faster for you,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Oracle database version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812929/how-to-get-oracle-database-version)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`select banner from v$version;`

should work.

you can also use.

`select version from PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION where rownum = 1;`

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple ways, to list a few of them :

1.

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum=1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```

2.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec dbms_output.put_line(dbms_db_version.version||'.'||dbms_db_version.release);
12.1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

3.

```
SQL> SELECT VERSION FROM V$INSTANCE;

VERSION
-----------------
12.1.0.1.0
```

4.

```
SQL> select version from PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION where rownum = 1;

VERSION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12.1.0.1.0
```

Comment: Is the version string somehow normalized? Or are solutions trying to extract the version _number_ from the version _string_ subject to break on subsequent release of Oracle?

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux, which step are you referring to? Steps 1 and 4 are straightforward. Steps 2 and 3 are an extract.

Comment: Alright, I edited the version from v$instance, I didn't realize I used susbtr. Edited it to get complete version string.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;
```

Answer (score 2):

For serverside versions:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;
```

For client side versions, it depends on the client. i.e for python:

```
import cx_Oracle as ora
print ora.version
```

Answer (score 0):

As a complement, if you are using an OCI-based client interface:

- [OCIServerVersion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14250/oci16msc007.htm#i540674) will return the version string of the Oracle server
- [OCIClientVersion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14250/oci16msc007.htm#BJFIBFAI) will return the version string of your Oracle client