# How to get Oracle database version?

Tags: sql, oracle, version

How to get Oracle database version from **sqlplus**, Oracle SQL developer, SQL Navigator or other IDE?

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You seem to have answered it already.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Execute this statement from SQL*Plus, SQLcl, Oracle SQL Developer, SQL Navigator or other IDE:

```
select * from product_component_version
```

And you'll get:

```
PRODUCT                                VERSION    VERSION_FULL STATUS
-------------------------------------- ---------- ------------ ----------
Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition 18.0.0.0.0 18.3.0.0.0   Production
```

Comment: Why do you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 16):

Try running this query in SQLPLUS -

```
select * from v$version
```

Answer (score 1):

**Soultion:**

Used this command **SELECT * FROM V$VERSION** It will show detail about oracle version in the SQL Developer.

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```